# Best way to export stage in kineticjs

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I'm looking for best way to export kinetic stage to json. Is there any solution to export objects with events, and custom attributes?

Comment: What about [Kinetic.toJSON](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-save-stage-as-json-string-with-kineticjs/)? Would it help?

Comment: Not realy, Kinetic.toJSON export just part of attributes without events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered, object.toJSON will not serialize your event handlers.

So you must:

- Use toJSON to serialize most of the object, and
- Put your KineticJS event handlers in a separate .js file, and
- Rewire them up after you deserialize the object.

Here's an example that almost automatically rewires the events:

**Step#1:** Create a separate kEvents.js file with the event handlers defined in an object:

```
// the eventHandlers object contains all the event handling functions
// for the serialized object(s).

var eventHandlers={
    myClickHandler1:function(e){alert("Fired clickHandler1");},
    myOtherClickHandler:function(e){alert("Fired the other clickHandler");},
}
```

**Step#2:** Add some attributes to your Kinetic nodes that indicate which handler(s) to rewire:

```
// this circle will be rewired with the click handler named "myClickHandler1"

var circle1 = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x:100,
    y:100,
    radius: 30,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4,
    draggable: true,

    // Below: 
    // "clickEvent" attribute indicates this node needs their click event rewired
    // "myClickHandler1" is the name of the handler function that will be rewired

    clickEvent:"myClickHandler1"
});
```

**Step#3:** Import the kEvents.js file

```
<script src="http://yourSite.com/kEvents.js"></script>
```

**Step#4:** Run a function that attaches the handlers in `eventHandlers` to the objects:

```
function rewireHandlers(node){

    var handler;

    // rewire click handler

    handler=node.getAttr("clickEvent");
    if(handler && eventHandlers[handler]){
        node.on("click",eventHandlers[handler])
    }

    // rewire other event handlers the same way

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is good answer but i haven't enough points to click on up arrow :)

Comment: If you have images, you have to reload them as well, just as the event handlers.